# http object status question

Tags: javascript, http, object, windows-ce

I am using http object in javascript on a hand held device, running Win CE.  When the device looses connection to the network, the javascript does not report an error (status = 12007) for 60-90 sec.  When connected to the network, the status (200) is returned immediately.  In both cases the readystate = 4.

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly is your problem?

Comment: The problem is the time it takes for a status of 12007 to be returned.  The 200 status is almost immediate.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like there is a timeout for the connection, so no error occurs until that much time has elapsed.

Comment: Are you referring to the timeout for the http object??  If so, where can I set that??  How can I specify to check for a specific status (ie 12007)???

Comment: Sorry, I'm not a WinCE programmer, so I don't know the API well enough to help you. I've just had similar problems before in other domains. The Java JDBC connection, in particular, had a crazy "never-timeout" (if there was a timeout, it was REALLY long) setting that couldn't be configured for a very long time; you had to use a custom wrapper.